# accessing a class variable in C (Arduino Timezone library)

Tags: c++, c, class

I am trying to use the timezone library for Arduino. 
https://github.com/JChristensen/Timezone/blob/master/examples/Clock/Clock.pde

Here, the timezone is initialized globally, and then printed in the loop()

```
//Line numbers used for reference. Not part of code.
1.TimeChangeRule myDST = {"EDT", Second, Sun, Mar, 2, -240};    //Daylight time = UTC - 4 hours
2.TimeChangeRule mySTD = {"EST", First, Sun, Nov, 2, -300};     //Standard time = UTC - 5 hours
3.Timezone myTZ(myDST, mySTD);
```

I want to change myTZ(dst,std) based on user input. This will happen inside a function. But when I try to do like this even right after line 3

```
myTZ(mySTD, mySTD);
```

I get an error

```
no matching function for call to 'Timezone::Timezone()'
```

I am not well versed with classes. How can I use myTZ as a global instance, and set it/ change it/ use it in other functions?

Comment: Are you trying to re-initialize your variable `myTZ = Timezone myTZ()`(no arguments)?

Comment: @CristiFati No, not reinitialize with no arguments. Rather, update with different Timechangerules. And Have it accessible from anywhere. What is the syntax to do something like myTZ(newrule1,new rule2)? Right now, I have to write Timezone myTZ(newrule1, newrule2) inside a function, which seems to be an entirely different variable.

Comment: Either way it's not correct. `myTZ(newrule1,new rule2)` calls a Constructor, which should only called once when the object is initialized. Your second method indeed creates a new variable: variables inside functions are stored on the stack which gets thrown away at the functions end, and variables go out of scope (there is an exception, but it's not relevant here). What you could do is pass the `Timezone` object (a ref or a pointer) as an parameter to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've looked over the `Timezone` definition in the link provided. Seems like once the object is created with the `TimeChangeRule`s, those can no longer be changed from code (except by calling `readRules` which isn't what you want).
So, you can have your `Timezone` object just like now:

```
Timezone myTZ(myDST, mySTD);
```

and the function that attempts to modify it could be:

```
void tzObjectModifier(Timezone &rTZ) {
    //perform all the operations(including reading user's input) to initialize newDST and newSTD TimeChangeRule objects
    rTZ(newDST, newSTD);
    //other additional statements
}
```

call the function against `myTZ` object like:

```
tzObjectModifier(myTZ);
```

and after the function exits, the global `myTZ` will have the content that you set from inside the function.

Comment: I can declare Timezone myTZ(myDST, mySTD); globally, but  if I need to call tzObjectModifier(myTZ); from inside a function that did not get it as an argument, can I still use it? like a global variable

Comment: If you want to use it as a global var, it means that it has to have setters for the 2 `TimeChangeRule`s, which you want to change from your function, but `Timezone` doesn't.